# Possible to put autoplay on <a> tag? (Lightbox)

Tags: html, video

I've set up a website, and the way i did that i can't just iframe a video or use the  tag. Is there any way to put some sort of autoplay on an  tag? I'm talking like javascript if needed or any other language. i just want to know.

*EDIT: I'm using lightbox

*EDIT2: I'm trying to make it so that when i click on the a tag, the lightbox shows up and the video starts playing. I've already made it so it pops up on the screen, but i'm unable to click the video, and it just closes it again. That's why i want it to autoplay.

```html
<a href="#" data-videoid="OyeBGqIrjwg" data-videosite="youtube" class="button video link-lightbox">
                        WATCH VIDEO <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
```

Comment: It's unclear if your goal here is to make the video autoplay when the "link" is clicked and the lightbox opens or if it is to open the lightbox without the visitor clicking on anything.

Comment: unfortunately i needed to flag this as should be closed because it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Harry I'm sorry, wrote this in a hurry before i went to bed, and hoped for some awnsers the next day. Hopefully my edit made it a bit more clear what i wanted help with.

Comment: It is good that you changed your question and added details. Unfortunately i still cannot help because "i am using lightbox" is not enough information. The way you use your href makes me assume that you include some external javascript that helps embedding youtube videos. In this javascript the url of the video must be changed so "&autoplay=1" is added to the youtube url

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can do a autoclic on your link with javascript like that..

```
<a id="videoLink" href="#" data-videoid="OyeBGqIrjwg" data-videosite="youtube" class="button video link-lightbox">
  WATCH VIDEO <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
/** SCRIPT TO AUTO CLIC ON LOAD IN LINK WITH ID="videoLink" **/
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        window.location = $('#videoLink').attr('href');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't click the link, it reads the value of the `href` attribute (which is blank) and makes the browser visit the URL. I'm not sure what behaviour that would cause: It will either do nothing at all or stuck the browser in an infinite reload loop. Neither of those makes the code useful.